# Adding an active state to list item using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following HTML markup:-

```
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li ng-repeat="track in songTracks track by $index" ng-class="{active: $index===selectedIndex}">
                            <a ng-click="setSongTrack(track)">
                                {{track.name}}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

In Angular, I use this:-

```
                    $scope.setSongTrack = setSongTrack;
                    $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
                    $scope.index= function(i) {
                      $scope.selectedIndex=i;
                    };
```

Which passes to DASHJS like so:-

```
                    function setSongTrack(track) {
                        musicPlayer.setSongTrack(track);
                        $scope.selectedIndex = track;
                    }
```

musicPlayer being the instance of DASHJS, which parses my audio tracks. This all works - I get a bunch of list elements with the track names, I can click them and independently load each track as expected. However, I need to add some visual way of informing the user which track is currently selected, which is probably best done by way of adding a CSS 'active' class.

Currently this just sets an 'active' class to the first list element, regardless if I click another and it changes the track. If I click another list item, the 'active' class is removed from the first list item. I need the 'active' class to only be on the currently selected track, i.e. the selected list item.

Now I'm stumped. I've read over a lot of similar SO questions and haven't located something which I can get to work.

Can anyone enlighten me? Fairly new to Angular and so, I'm still a bit of a noob with it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the index of the track to mark it as selected, use the track itself. Write a function like `trackSelected()` which takes a track, and use that to apply a class with `ngClass`. Eg...

#### HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="track in songTracks track by $index" ng-class="{ 'active': isSelected(track)} ">
        <a ng-click="setSongTrack(track)" ng-bind="track.name">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### JS

```
$scope.selectedTrack = null;

$scope.setSongTrack = function(track) {
    musicPlayer.setSongTrack(track);
    $scope.selectedTrack = track;
}

$scope.isSelected = function(track) {
    return $scope.selectedTrack === track;
}
```

This is because you may add or remove tracks from the list in your view at some point, and then the selected index will be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

just go like this:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li ng-repeat="track in songTracks track by $index" ng-class="{active: track===selectedTrack}">
        <a ng-click="setSongTrack(track)">
            {{track.name}}
        </a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

and in your js

```
$scope.selectedTrack = undefined;
$scope.setSongTrack = function (track) {
  musicPlayer.setSongTrack(track);
  $scope.selectedTrack = track;
}
```

This way you can also do stuff like presenting the selected track in your player like below just with one click, no need to fiddle with indexes and such.

```
<h1>{{selectedTrack.name}}</h1>
<p>
   <span>{{selectedTrack.totalTime}}</span>
</p>
```

[Here is a simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgpsuxak/)

### Alternate Solution

Going the `$index` way should be like this(Just explaining to help you see what you did wrong)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li ng-repeat="track in songTracks track by $index" ng-class="{active: $index===selectedIndex}">
        <a ng-click="setSongTrackIndex($index)">
            {{track.name}}
        </a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Notice that i chanced `setSongTrack(track)` to `setSongTrackIndex($index)`. Then you would of course change your js accordingly, like so:

```
function setSongTrackIndex(trackIndex) {
    musicPlayer.setSongTrack(songTracks[trackIndex]);
    $scope.selectedIndex = trackIndex;
}

$scope.setSongTrack = setSongTrack;
$scope.selectedIndex = 0;
```

If you need further explanation please comment.

Comment: I tried this method, all that happened is the active class got added to each list element upon page load, clicking the list items did change the track, but the active class did not change? Sorry, commented before you added Alternate Solution, which I will try now.

Comment: I added a simple fiddle for the first solution, check it out.

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot to understand what was going on and thankfully, it works!